# ShareThis Facebook share button doesn't find images on a page

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-sharer, sharethis

The ShareThis Facebook button will only pull the logo as an image to choose from a page. I am not sure why this is the case since I have other images on pages that I am trying to share from. Can someone help me out with this. I am not really familiar with the ShareThis API. Thanks for any help or feedback.

I tried using the Facebook URL Debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug. When doing so, Facebook found all the images on the page, but ShareThis doesn't seem to do the same. That is why I am guessing it is a ShareThis related issue.

The client wants the person posting the page/blog post to be able to select the image from the images on the page. This is normally the case with the ShareThis API, but does not seem to do so. Otherwise I would have just used the open graph option.

URL of site: http://www.atranquilnook.com/

1-30-14: I tried specifying an image with open graph meta on a page. The image was larger than 200 x 200, but it still did not work.

This appears to be happening on every page of the site.

Note: *I did not build this site. It was built in Adobe Muse by someone else.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a real answer, but I have to use the space here, to get you all the details of what I found out.

On the debugger it says https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.atranquilnook.com%2F :

Provided og:image is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200 px. Image 'http://www.atranquilnook.com/images/header-home03.png' will be used instead.

Since there is the image with the couple, which is bigger than 200px x 200px, I do not know if this is the answer, but you could try by uploading some bigger image.

Although the whole warning is deceptive, since a line above it states, that there is no `og:image`.

Comment: I did notice that and was confused as to why it was not pulling that picture of the couple out of the page.

Comment: @Phorden Maybe there is an `og:image` set on another page? Is this a blog? Do you have the same `meta` on every page? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories#propertytypes You can also set several `og:image`. Maybe dynamically with Javascript? What happens if you try to set an `og:image`, for example the couple?

Comment: It is a regular site built in Adobe Muse, but it has a blog component built into it. The biggest issue with setting the og:image is I do not want to set the image every time the client makes a blog post.

Comment: @Phorden I see, I just want to know what the debugger says, if you put up the couple image, if he still says: too small!?!

Comment: It does not seem to make a difference even if I set the open graph meta in the head of the page. http://prntscr.com/2nxgaf

Comment: I rechecked the page after putting in the meta tag, and it is saying the image I am using is too small even though it is larger than the 200 x 200 requirement. I am stumped.

Comment: @Phorden hmm, at least you know the mistake is on facebook side, let's see how to circumvent that.

Comment: I do not know what the solution is, but unless someone else gives me an answer within the hour, I am giving the bounty to you as you have tried to be the most helpful.

Comment: @Phorden Thanks, but I am still in, cause I need that feature in the future. ;) So I pasted a page which has one bigger image and two small https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=Liebdich.biz%2F%3Farea%3Dmusic and it does not say anything about the "image too small" in relation to og:image, i guess somewhere on the page there is an og:image set, can you confirm that it is not?!?

Comment: Are you referring to the page you provided or the page on my website?

Comment: @Phorden Thanks for giving me the reputation first. ;) I meant your page as in your website, since I do not know if Adobe Muse uses something like a CMS or creates every single page... However I had another hunch, since it is not validating http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=atranquilnook.com&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 you could try to delete all the Adobe Muse own meta tags, perhaps then the images get found?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are relying on Facebook being smart enough to find "better" image on your site. What you should do instead is adding a meta tag in the head section of your page.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.yoursite.com/img/some-image.jpg"/>
```

This will tell Facebook exactly what you want to rest of the world to see.

Comment: The issue is that the client wants the person posting to Facebook to be able to choose the image from the blog post. Since I would be setting the image this way, it would be the same image for each blog post. I would agree that this would be the best approach normally.

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect this need. Thank you for your feedback though.

Comment: I have also tried this with images on the site larger than 200 x 200 with no success.